# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to use pickle.load()

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pickle

First, I dumped this information into a file called 'save0.pickle'.

```
with open('save0.pickle', 'wb') as outfile:
    pickle.dump({
        'world_w': world.w,
        'world_h': world.h,
        'world_world': world.world,
        'player_icon': player.icon,
        'player_x': player.x,
        'player_y': player.y,
        'player_item': player.item,
    }, outfile)
```

This worked fine, however I get an error when I try to load the file's information into a variable, as shown below.

```
with open('save0.pickle', 'r') as infile:
    d = pickle.load(infile)
```

Error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 21: character maps to <undefined>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try opening the file in binary/bytes mode. `..open("save0.pickle", "rb") ..`

Comment: That worked! Thanks :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521034/keith) said, changing `open("save0.pickle", "r")` to `open("save0.pickle", "rb")` solved the problem.